# Куда добавить заголово HTTP

Tags: apache, nginx, centos, веб-сервер

На сайте используется связка nginx + apache. На https перешли давно, а вот про заголовок `Strict-Transport-Security`узнали не давно. Сейчас есть только редирект на стороне php: `redirect('https://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);`. На сервере лежат несколько конфигов для веб-серверов, подскажите куда вписывать заголовок?
**site.ru.nginx.conf**

```
server {
listen      ip_server:80;
server_name site.ru *.site.ru;
error_log  /var/log/httpd/domains/site.ru.error.log error;

location / {
    proxy_pass      http://ip_server:8080;
    location ~* ^.+\.(jpeg|jpg|png|gif|bmp|ico|svg|tif|tiff|css|js|htm|html|ttf|otf|webp|woff|txt|csv|rtf|doc|docx|xls|xlsx|ppt|pptx|odf|odp|ods|odt|pdf|psd|ai|eot|eps|ps|zip|tar|tgz|gz|rar|bz2|7z|aac|m4a|mp3|mp4|ogg|wav|wma|3gp|avi|flv|m4v|mkv|mov|mpeg|mpg|wmv|exe|iso|dmg|swf)$ {
        root           /home/admin/web/site.ru/public_html;
        access_log     /var/log/httpd/domains/site.ru.log combined;
        access_log     /var/log/httpd/domains/site.ru.bytes bytes;
        expires        max;
        try_files      $uri @fallback;
    }
}

location /error/ {
    alias   /home/admin/web/site.ru/document_errors/;
}

location @fallback {
    proxy_pass      http://ip_server:8080;
}

location ~ /\.ht    {return 404;}
location ~ /\.svn/  {return 404;}
location ~ /\.git/  {return 404;}
location ~ /\.hg/   {return 404;}
location ~ /\.bzr/  {return 404;}

include /home/admin/conf/web/nginx.site.ru.conf*;
}
```

**site.ru.nginx.ssl.conf**

```
server {
listen      ip_server:443;
server_name site.ru *.site.ru;
ssl         on;
ssl_certificate      /home/admin/conf/web/ssl.site.ru.pem;
ssl_certificate_key  /home/admin/conf/web/ssl.site.ru.key;
error_log  /var/log/httpd/domains/site.ru.error.log error;

location / {
    proxy_pass      https://ip_server:8443;
    location ~* ^.+\.(jpeg|jpg|png|gif|bmp|ico|svg|tif|tiff|css|js|htm|html|ttf|otf|webp|woff|txt|csv|rtf|doc|docx|xls|xlsx|ppt|pptx|odf|odp|ods|odt|pdf|psd|ai|eot|eps|ps|zip|tar|tgz|gz|rar|bz2|7z|aac|m4a|mp3|mp4|ogg|wav|wma|3gp|avi|flv|m4v|mkv|mov|mpeg|mpg|wmv|exe|iso|dmg|swf)$ {
        root           /home/admin/web/site.ru/public_html;
        access_log     /var/log/httpd/domains/site.ru.log combined;
        access_log     /var/log/httpd/domains/site.ru.bytes bytes;
        expires        max;
        try_files      $uri @fallback;
    }
}

location /error/ {
    alias   /home/admin/web/site.ru/document_errors/;
}

location @fallback {
    proxy_pass      https://ip_server:8443;
}

location ~ /\.ht    {return 404;}
location ~ /\.svn/  {return 404;}
location ~ /\.git/  {return 404;}
location ~ /\.hg/   {return 404;}
location ~ /\.bzr/  {return 404;}

include /home/admin/conf/web/snginx.site.ru.conf*;
}
```

**site.ru.httpd.conf**

```
<VirtualHost ip_server:8080>

ServerName site.ru
ServerAlias *.site.ru
ServerAdmin info@site.ru
DocumentRoot /home/admin/web/site.ru/public_html
ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /home/admin/web/site.ru/cgi-bin/
Alias /vstats/ /home/admin/web/site.ru/stats/
Alias /error/ /home/admin/web/site.ru/document_errors/
#SuexecUserGroup admin admin
CustomLog /var/log/httpd/domains/site.ru.bytes bytes
CustomLog /var/log/httpd/domains/site.ru.log combined
ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/domains/site.ru.error.log
<Directory /home/admin/web/site.ru/public_html>
    AllowOverride All
    Options +Includes -Indexes +ExecCGI
    php_admin_value open_basedir /home/admin/web/site.ru/public_html:/home/admin/tmp
    php_admin_value upload_tmp_dir /home/admin/tmp
    php_admin_value session.save_path /home/admin/tmp
</Directory>
<Directory /home/admin/web/site.ru/stats>
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>

<IfModule mod_ruid2.c>
    RMode config
    RUidGid admin admin
    RGroups apache
</IfModule>
<IfModule itk.c>
    AssignUserID admin admin
</IfModule>

IncludeOptional /home/admin/conf/web/httpd.site.ru.conf*
```

**site.ru.httpd.ssl.conf**

```
<VirtualHost ip_server:8443>

ServerName site.ru
ServerAlias *.site.ru
ServerAdmin info@site.ru
DocumentRoot /home/admin/web/site.ru/public_html
ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /home/admin/web/site.ru/cgi-bin/
Alias /vstats/ /home/admin/web/site.ru/stats/
Alias /error/ /home/admin/web/site.ru/document_errors/
#SuexecUserGroup admin admin
CustomLog /var/log/httpd/domains/site.ru.bytes bytes
CustomLog /var/log/httpd/domains/site.ru.log combined
ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/domains/site.ru.error.log
<Directory /home/admin/web/site.ru/public_html>
    AllowOverride All
    SSLRequireSSL
    Options +Includes -Indexes +ExecCGI
    php_admin_value open_basedir /home/admin/web/site.ru/public_html:/home/admin/tmp
    php_admin_value upload_tmp_dir /home/admin/tmp
    php_admin_value session.save_path /home/admin/tmp
</Directory>
<Directory /home/admin/web/site.ru/stats>
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
SSLEngine on
SSLVerifyClient none
SSLCertificateFile /home/admin/conf/web/ssl.site.ru.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /home/admin/conf/web/ssl.site.ru.key
SSLCertificateChainFile /home/admin/conf/web/ssl.site.ru.ca

<IfModule mod_ruid2.c>
    RMode config
    RUidGid admin admin
    RGroups apache
</IfModule>
<IfModule itk.c>
    AssignUserID admin admin
</IfModule>

IncludeOptional /home/admin/conf/web/shttpd.site.ru.conf*
```

**htaccess**

```
DirectorySlash Off
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule favicon.ico$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^crossdomain.xml$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^data/export - [L]
RewriteRule index.php.* - [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*) index.php
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
  #The following line is enough for .js and .css
  AddOutputFilter DEFLATE js css

 #The following line also enables compression by file content type, for the following list of Content-Type:s
 AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml application/xml

 #The following lines are to avoid bugs with some browsers
 BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
 BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip
 BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
 <FilesMatch "\.(js|css|xml|gz)$">
  Header append Vary: Accept-Encoding
 </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/png "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType text/css "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/html "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/pdf "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access 1 year"
ExpiresDefault "access 1 month"
 </IfModule>

  php_value       default_charset         UTF-8
  php_value       mbstring.language       Russian
  php_value       mbstring.internal_encoding      UTF-8
  php_flag        mbstring.encoding_translation   on
  php_value       mbstring.http_input     UTF-8
  php_value       mbstring.http_output    UTF-8
  php_value       mbstring.detect_order   UTF-8
```

Comment: Добавил в ssl.nginx так как он выступает в качестве фронта